# How to make draggable object droppable aftrer it being dropped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I apologize if the question is formulated sloppy. I'm just somewhere in the beginning of understanding jquery.

I want to implement a form builder based on drag and drop.

Don't know how to make a draggable object droppable after it being dropped.

In my I am looking for this scenario:

dragging "Auth" block, drop it, appears a div, after this I drag "Second" block and I can drop it both to "Auth" block and main droppable zone.

jsfiddle.net/284mx1vn/3/

Comment: Opening the fiddle doesn't show any blocks such as "*Auth" block*"... Because it is only visible in certain screen size... I accidently saw it... Please update the question with relevant code, steps to do whatever you're talking about in the fiddle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize the element you're creating in drag event as draggable by wrapping in in a jquery object as follows:

```
var $field = $('<div class="input-block"><span class="label label-primary">' + ui.draggable.text() + '</span><div class="auth-block"></div>' + $add + $del + '</div>');
            $field.appendTo(this).find(".auth-block").droppable({
                drop: function(e,ui){
                    $(this).append(ui.draggable); // anything else you want to do
                }
            });
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/284mx1vn/4/embedded/result/) (*Fullscreen result*)

*Side note: You should really re-factor the code for creating the template, maybe by adding a separate function for creating templates... currently it is hard to work with it as it is*